# Guessing the distribution of two random variables from their product distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and I know the distribution of their product $Z = X Y$. It is distributed as a power law
$$ PDF_Z(z) = A z^{-\alpha} $$
where there naturally is a lower cutoff $z > z_0$.

I'm trying to figure out if based on this I can say anything about the distributions of the variables $X$ and $Y$.

The idea I have so far is to write $CDF_Z$ using the joint distribution $PDF_{X,Y}(x, y)$ by calculating this integral
$$ CDF_Z(z) = \int_{x=x_{min}}^{x=x_{max}} \int_{y=\frac{z_0}{x}}^{y=\frac{z}{x}} PDF_{X,Y}(x, y) \, \mathrm{d} y \, \mathrm{d} x $$
where I could for example make an ansatz of the power law form $PDF_{X,Y}(x, y) = B x^{-\beta} y^{-\gamma}$ and see what comes out as the distribution of the product.

The calculation is
\begin{align*}
CDF_Z(z) &= B
\int_{x=x_{min}}^{x=x_{max}} x^{-\beta}
\int_{y=\frac{z_0}{x}}^{y=\frac{z}{x}} y^{-\gamma} \, \mathrm{d} y 
\, \mathrm{d} x \\
&= \frac{B}{1-\gamma}
\int_{x=x_{min}}^{x=x_{max}} x^{-\beta}
\left[
\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)^{1-\gamma}
- \left(\frac{z_0}{x}\right)^{1-\gamma}
\right]
\, \mathrm{d} x \\
&= \frac{B}{1-\gamma} \left(
z^{1-\gamma} - z_0^{1-\gamma}
\right)
\int_{x=x_{min}}^{x=x_{max}} x^{\gamma-1-\beta}
\, \mathrm{d} x \\
&= \frac{B}{1-\gamma} \frac{x_{max}^{\gamma-\beta} - x_{min}^{\gamma-\beta}}{\gamma-\beta} 
\left(
z^{1-\gamma} - z_0^{1-\gamma} 
\right)
= C \left(
z^{1-\gamma} - z_0^{1-\gamma} 
\right)
\end{align*}
which would directly imply
$$ PDF_Z(z) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} CDF_Z(z)
= C \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \left(
z^{1-\gamma} - z_0^{1-\gamma} 
\right)
= C z^{-\gamma} \mathrm{.}$$

I'm slightly confused about this. It seems to imply that only the exponent $\gamma$ in the power law of the joint distribution has an effect on the exponent of the product distribution (meaning that I should have $\gamma = \alpha$) and that the exponent $\beta$ only has an effect on the normalization factor $C$.

Is there some fundamental flaw in my thinking or is a valid way of arguing that "if the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ would look like this it would produce the known distribution for their product $Z = X Y$"?

Answer (score 1):

Since $W:=\ln Z=\ln X +\ln Y$ and $Z$ has pdf $Az^{-\alpha}$ on $z>z_0$ iff $\ln Z$ has pdf $Ae^{-(\alpha -1)w}$ on $w>\ln z_0$, you're trying to express an exponential distribution (in the special case $z_0=1$, which I'll stick to hereafter because the problems it encounters are instructive) as the sum of two independent exponential distributions. (You didn't *mention* independence, but your PDF Ansatz is of the form $p(x)q(y)$ for functions $p,\,q$, so implies $X,\,Y$ are independent.) This is the wrong choice of Ansatz. In particular $U:=\ln X,\,V:=\ln Y$ each have characteristic functions of the form $(1-\frac{it}{\lambda})^{-1}$, so $U+V$ has a characteristic function of the form $(1-\frac{it}{\lambda_1})^{-1}(1-\frac{it}{\lambda_2})^{-1}$, which isn't of the form $(1-\frac{it}{\lambda})^{-1}$. Obviously, if an inappropriate Ansatz is assumed you'll get nonsensical results.

Although I couldn't find a proof or reference, it's mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Probability_density_function) that the exponential distribution is infinitely divisible, i.e. $W$ can be represented as the sum of $n$ IIDs for any $n\in\Bbb N$. Thus we can choose $U$ to be the some of $k$ of them and $V$ the sum of $l$ of them, and so one can't be *very* precise about the distributions of $U,\,V$ or indeed of $X,\,Y$.